# How to know when AVPlayerItem is playing

Tags: ios, avqueueplayer

I am having a problem with `AVPlayerItem` and `AVQueuePlayer`. Currently i have a lot of music files which are 1-2 sec long and a queue Player for playing them in sequence.

What I want is to know when a music file **has just started playing** and not when it has finished playing(via `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification`).

This is because i want to run a function when a new file is loaded and played.

My code:

```
 for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [matchedAddr count]; i++)
{
    NSString *firstVideoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[matchedAddr objectAtIndex:i] ofType:@"wav"];
    //NSLog(@"file %@",firstVideoPath);
    avitem=[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:firstVideoPath]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(currentItemIs:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:avitem];

    [filelist addObject:avitem];
}
 player = [AVQueuePlayer queuePlayerWithItems:filelist];
[player play];


- (void)currentItemIs:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSString *asd=[seqArray objectAtIndex:currentColor];
    currentColor=currentColor+1;
    AVPlayerItem *p = [notification object];
    [p seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];

    if([asd isEqual:@"1"])
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.01 animations:^{
           one.alpha = 0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.01 animations:^{
               one.alpha = 1;
            }];
        }];
    }
}
```

As you can see,the `currentItemIs` void is called but it runs when the track has finished playing.I want to be called when the track is at the beginning.

**EDIT:**
Updated version of Winston's snippet:

```
NSString * const kStatusKey         = @"status";

        [avitem addObserver:self
                              forKeyPath:kStatusKey
                                 options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                                 context:@"AVPlayerStatus"];
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)path
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {

    if (context == @"AVPlayerStatus") {

        AVPlayerStatus status = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] integerValue];
        switch (status) {
            case AVPlayerStatusUnknown: {

            }
                break;

            case AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay: {
                // audio will begin to play now.
                NSLog(@"PLAU");
                [self playa];
            }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to register your `AVPlayerItem` as an **observer**:

```
[self.yourPlayerItem addObserver:self
                      forKeyPath:kStatus
                         options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                         context:AVPlayerStatus];
```

Then on your player **Key Value Observer** method you need to check for `AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay` **status**, like so:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)path
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {

     if (context == AVPlayerStatus) {

        AVPlayerStatus status = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] integerValue];
        switch (status) {
            case AVPlayerStatusUnknown: {

            }
            break;

            case AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay: {
                // audio will begin to play now.
            }
            break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Let me test i will get back2u.

Comment: OK. I've made some modifications, please the code again. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, it worked,i have added my final code with corrections.

Comment: Great! I'm really glad that I could help you. Thanks.

Comment: This is great, except for remote files there is a noticeable gap between ReadyToPlay being fired and the audio actually starting.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that as well.

Comment: Is this really correct? Is readyToPlay really meaning that the avplayeritem **is** playing?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The audio will start playing when it reaches AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay.

Comment: I think there is something need to be corrected, you added observer to your `playerItem` and then defining  `AVPlayerStatus` as context + checking `AVPlayerStatus`. Instead of `AVPlayerStatus` you should check `#keyPath(AVPlayer.currentItem.status)` or `AVPlayerItem.Status` because your observer added for item not the player.

Answer (score 4):

Following should work:

**Observe the Player's State:**

```
let playerItem: AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: videoPlusSubtitles, automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: requiredAssetKeys)

playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status), options: [], context: nil)

player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
```

---

**Respond to a State Change:**

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status) {
        let status: AVPlayerItem.Status

        if let statusNumber = change?[.newKey] as? NSNumber {
            status = AVPlayerItem.Status(rawValue: statusNumber.intValue)!
        } else {
            status = .unknown
        }

        // Switch over status value
        switch status {
        case .readyToPlay:
            print("Player item is ready to play.")
            break
        case .failed:
            print("Player item failed. See error")
            break
        case .unknown:
            print("Player item is not yet ready")
            break
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one thing, in options: put `[.new, .old]`